# Which is better: Selecting across linked servers vs migrating the database

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server

I have a customer that needs to query a linked server to produce a report. They will be joining a linked server table with a local table.

Is it better to just let them do the select across the linked server OR migrate (backup/restore) the database every day and have there query run against 2 local databases?

For discussion sake let's say the query returns 20K records.

Comment: If performance is important, and you do not want the administration of the linked server, then, running the report locally sounds like a better option.  I would compare the Report's response times of both methods and base a decision off of that.

Comment: Are you limited to only these options?

Comment: You can publish the database instead of backup/restore.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik No. Those are the only options I am familiar with

Comment: @McNets Publish? I have only read access to the linked server database

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely get the best performance by copying the content of the remote table locally first, then running the query.  Especially if you filter the remote table through a remote view or a stored proc on the remote server.

Joining across a linked server can be brutal on performance depending on the implementation details of the query.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik spelling edits FTW

Comment: @Wes I had Richie write a bot that checks Max's posts for typos.

Comment: Thanks, Erik!  Stupid me attempting to answer on mobile, again.

Comment: @MaxVernon Even after 10 years, typing on phones is horrible.